# Why does a less probable event yield more information?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

I'm trying to wrap my around entropy as defined in information theory, and it states for Shannon information an axiom:

> The less probable an event is, the more surprising it is and the more information it yields.

I know this is an axiom, so it's kind of inappropriate to ask for proof, but do we just have to take this as given? Or is it intuitive that this is true? What "information" am I gaining from witnessing a less probable outcome? If I had a magic coin that took different probabilities to land on different faces for each toss, why would the one where $p_{heads} = p_{tails} = 0.5$ provide me the "most information"?

Comment: For intuition, assume that if the coin toss yields heads, it rains that day and if it it yields tails, it will be a sunny day. Now if the coin is so biased that it always lands as heads (100% of the time), what information is the coin toss giving? It is always going to be rainy. So there isn't any information being given by the coin toss. However, a 50-50 coin will give a lot more information on what kind of day it will be.

Comment: @Paddy Sure, but the main takeaway I'm getting from that is "a 50-50 coin will tell someone that days can be sunny or rainy" but so can a 90-10, 80-20, 70-30 coin, yet the information gain will be maximized for 50-50.

Comment: This is pretty interesting to think about. Would you say the statements - "there are 10 oranges in the basket" and "there are 264239472974 oranges in the basket" have the same amount of information or different amounts of information?

Comment: @Paddy The latter will likely provide more information because it implies there are 10 oranges in the basket, and more than that up to that big number. Still, this is just a consequence of the math behind information gain, and not an intuitive justification for 50-50 providing the most information. Also, is information gain *even telling you* how many oranges are in the basket in the first place?

Comment: What if we think geometrically?  A probability one event has no information because we already know it's happening.  A probability $\epsilon$ event carries a lot of information because it is a very small portion of "phase space:" if we imagine partitioning the space into $\epsilon^{-1}$ disjoint chunks, then this event uniquely identifies which of these (very many) chunks we're in.  We can throw out all the other chunks; we are zeroing on which outcome we're in.

Comment: @sangstar I am not trying to answer your question here. Why should the bigger number have more information considering that they are answering the same question - how many oranges there are. The answer in both cases is an integer and there isn't even probability involved. The only reason why the bigger number has "more" information is if you assume that you are defining information as the "space" required to represent the answer. Would you agree? If not, why do you think the bigger number has more information?

Comment: @Paddy I feel that you don't need to define information as the "space" (which I assume are in this case the number of digits/bits) required to represent the answer if this basket is the same basket in both statements. If it's the same basket, the second statement implicitly implies the first while providing additional information.

Answer (score 1):

@DonThousand 's comments offer a good point of view. I would like to offer another, which has the advantage that both the information granted by a single outcome and the Shannon entropy make intuitive sense.

Consider a population with some characteristics (age, gender, hair color, etc.). You want to find one individual based on his characteristics (assume they single him out uniquely).

When you ask a yes/no question, getting the least common trait is more useful, because it shrinks down more the pool of possible candidates : you just *gained* more information.

Now, when you are choosing the next question, to gain the most out of it, it is pretty clear you need to choose a question where both outcomes are as likely.

**Edit :** Some more explanations on that last point.

When you ask a question and get an answer that had a probability (here frequency) $p$, you are multiplying the number of possible individual by $p$. To compute an expectation, it makes sense to take the $\log$ : the information associated with this outcome is $-\log p$ and the expected information is the Shannon entropy :
$$S = -p\log p - (1-p)\log(1-p)$$

This is maximal for $p = 1/2$. If you want to find that person as quick as possible, the best strategy is dichotomy : try and find a question which splits the remaining population in $2$.

Comment: Does "least common" equate to "least probable"?

Comment: @sangstar Yes. It does.

Comment: I was following you until the last paragraph. I can agree that an uncommon trait will give you a lot more information about the person because it tells you about a lot of the thing *the person is not*. However, none of what you said prior makes it obvious to me that "you need to choose a question where both outcomes are as likely" -- I just know that I want to ask a yes/no question about whether this person has an uncommon trait or not, and as such I don't understand from this why 50-50 outcome questions maximize information gain.

Comment: Edited to hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of information is a little tricky here. A 10 bit number is said to have more information than a 5 bit number. If that number is say the number of watermelons in a basket, both numbers represent the same quantity, but different values have different amounts of "information".

So when you read the term "information" think of it as the number of bits used to represent that piece of information.

If some event keeps occuring with high probability (say people breathing in and out), you will want to assign lower number of bits to that event. All likely events will be assigned smaller amount of bits because it is easy to communicate that way. A more unlikely event (volcano eruption for instance) will be assigned a larger chunk of bits because all the lower bit combinations have already been taken up by the more likely events.

Now check out [Shannon Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_coding) and the example there. The best way to code data is essentially to assign lower number of bits to events that have higher probability and higher number of bits to events that have lower probability.

Comment: I don't really feel this answers my question. Judging from your answer, less probable events give more information gain because they "will be assigned a larger chunk of bits". But why are they given a larger chunk of bits? Because higher bit numbers are said to have "more information"? It sounds like we are *choosing* to give improbable events higher information gain rather than that being the case innately.